# Eclipse link JPA - Get only entity of associated table records

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am new to JPA. In my new project, we are using Eclipse Link JPA.

I have two tables. Students, Addresses. Each student may have multiple addresses(For address history). So one to many relationship. In StudentEntity.java file, I mentioned Set.

Now my question is, whenever I am fetching all student details, inside Set, I needed only one Addressed entry, based on created date in addresses table. That means When I fetch List using createQuery, how can I mention, associated table conditions.

### Example:-

StudentEntity

STUDENT1 --- John
STUDENT2 --- Robert

Addresses

Addr_id  - STU_ID     -- Addr1        --City             ---created date
1        - STUDENT1   -- latestadd    --latestcity       -- 23-8-2017
2        - STUDENT1   -- oldaddr      --oldcity          -- 12-8-2016

### Student:-

@OneToMany()
Set adddresses;

So when i don createQuery("select s from Students"), i want to get only address having addr_id = 1 which is latest address.

How can i achieve this using createQuery?

Comment: Are you looking to have the Student instance with the set containing only a single address? If that is the case, why map it?  Why not just query for the latest address instead of the student: "select a from address a fetch join a.student where a.id=1".  This will give you list of latest addresses, which you can use a.getStudent() to get the associated student, assuming you've set it up as a bidirectional relationship.

Comment: Ya. I need to get List of Students along with that each student should have only one address, which is latest in addresses list. It is bidirectional. So for that how we can fetch?

Comment: Have you tried "select a from address a fetch join a.student where a.id=1"?  Addresses returned will have students that match your criteria. Otherwise, "select s from Student s join s.addresses a where a.id =1" will give you all students with an address with ID=1.  You need to use the field in address that maps to the "addr_id" field in that table.

Comment: Hi Chris.. Thank you so much. It is working now. with fetch join i am getting only one record.  "select s from Student s join s.addresses a where a.id = 1" is giving result and also, for "@OneToMany" annotation we need to give "@JoinFetch". Then i am getting result.

Answer (score 1):

Got the required result with below query

Student s join s.addresses a where a.id = 1" is giving result and also, for "@OneToMany" annotation we need to give "@JoinFetch".

Answer (score 0):

Use createQuery("select s from Students where addr_id = 1")
As far as i can tell this is what you are asking for